# Element jr:Table is not allowed in jrxml file

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a jasper report containing a table (jr:table tag) within a Java application, having the **jasperreports** library version 6.11.0

I generated the **.jrxml** file template file using Jaspersoft Studio 6.11.0, and when I paste it within my IntelliJ IDE I get a warning like *jr:Table is not allowed here* and after generating the pdf containing the report, only the header of the report is found wihtin that pdf and no table.

Note: within the Jaspersoft Studio the table is generated correctly.
Also I get no error within the Java app logs.

[image]

Comment: `within my IntelliJ IDE I get a warning like jr:Table is not allowed here` - it is not a problem. You can ignore this warning. Looks like IDEA is using wrong xsd

Comment: The problem is that the final pdf report does not contain the table. I don't know If it's related to this warning or not.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?